# Securely store user affiliate codes

Tags: php, sql, filter, ads

I want to create article ad spaces where I can display user submitted ads. Like on hubpages.

For instance I can display Amazon ads by simply using a users amazon affiliate key but there are many affiliate programs and each use a different code. Ultimately the user will have to submit an entire script.

But how can store such data securely? Can I for instance save data to a text file and verify it before inserting in the database?

Or is there a super filter I can use to sanitize?.. not sure if there's a safe way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it in the database is not the part you should worry about.  There are many ways to clean data (escaping, regexes), as well as safer ways to insert it (prepared statements). Just search on SO.  Displaying it again is the tough part.  If they are allowed to upload scripts (javascript I'm assuming), the responsibility will be on you to make sure its not doing any crazy XSS attacks.  Which essentially means a manual review.